# How to login programmatically

Tags: support, authentication

I'm building an app for personal use. The app simply screen-scrapes the StackExchange homepage and checks whether I am currently logged in to StackExchange. This works fine.

However, if the app determines I am not logged in I would like the app to log me in. I have had a look at the [authentication](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) documentation, but to be honest I'm not sure what to do with that information. I *think* I need to use the implicit path but don't know what to supply for the required fields, i.e. client_id, scope, redirect_uri, state.

Any pointers would be gratefully received.

Comment: Logged into the (scraped) page is not the same as logged into, or authorized, for an app.  If you want the scraped page to be logged in, an approach like in [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/164032/148310) will work. Your scraper must be cookie and javascript savvy.

Comment: @BrockAdams Not necessarily; you could use a built in browser-view (or from a library) to get and render the page off-screen, then scrape this view.