# How to login programmatically on Android?

Tags: support, api, authentication, android

I think my question is not a duplicate of this one: [How to login programmatically](https://stackapps.com/q/3863)

I have read [the authentication document](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) but, still, I am unable to get what's needed to login programmatically on Android.

I mean, which URL should I pass to perform the login activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use implicit OAuth flow. Load the specified URL with necessary query parameters into a webview and when authentication is done you can get the access_token from the redirect_uri. You can have the webview handle the redirect_uri by setting a custom webview client.

Example:

```
private class ExampleWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {

            if (url.startsWith(MY_REDIRECT_URI))
            {
                //parse the URL here to get the access_token
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
}
```

And while initializing the webview, do

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new ExampleWebViewClient());
```

Comment: ok, so for login i must use webview only ? there is no method like a webservice. In case of above webview what could be a URL, can yo u give me a sample url please ?